# How do I delete many to many graphQL relationships with Apollo in react?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a ruby on rails API with graqhQL implemented and I'm using apollo in my react front end for queries and mutations. I'm a little confused on how to delete associations... I have 3 models 2 of which are connected through the third with a has many through association. Here's a sample query:

```
{
  "data": {
    "routes": [
      { "id": "33",
        "name": "test",
        "description": "rout",
        "locationsCount": 1,
        "routeLocations": [
          {
            "id": "32",
            "routeId": 33,
            "locationId": 19
          }
        ],
        "locations": [
          {
            "id": "19",
            "slug": "OKC"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

If I wanted to remove the routeLocation with id 32 how would I query that in the front end? Is it possible to use the locationId field to do so?

Comment: prepare [and test] deleting mutation first, it will help you discover required args [for your models/relations]